# "TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType" even though all input arrays have the same type

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ufunc

I'm trying to create a piece of software that calculates the density distribution inside a white dwarf by dividing it into a bunch of layers and running a crude physics simulation on them. I wrote some functions that I tried to vectorize, but I keep getting the error `TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType`.

From what I've been able to gather from other questions on this site, the culprit is probably running operations on entities with different types. So I tried rewriting the `frompyfunc()` statements to `vectorize` statements and tried setting the type to be `np.double`, `"double"`, and `"float64"`, but I ended up getting "invalid otype." And yes, I remembered to get rid of the `ninput` and `noutput` arguments when doing this.

I also tried setting all of my arrays to the type `double` and clarifying which variables were global in my original functions, but neither of those helped either.

This is the function

```
def selfBelow(m,r,x):   #The gravitational self-force of a layer below the border
    if x>r:
        return 3*G*m**2*x*(5*r**3 + 6*r**2*x + 3*r*x**2 + x*3) / (5*(r**2 + r*x + x**2)**3)
    else:
        return 1/0 #Return an error in this case because we need x to be greater than r
```

This is my attempt to vectorize it: `FSB = np.frompyfunc(selfBelow,2,1)`

And this is my attempt to call the vectorized function: `forces[0]-=FSB(masses[0], 0, radii[0])`

When I run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\White Dwarf.py", line 78, in <module>
    forces[0]-=FSB(masses[0], 0, radii[0])
TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType
```

Here's the full code in case you need it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

h=1.054571817e-34   #Reduced Planck constant
G=6.67430e-11   #Gravitational constant
m_e=9.10938370153e-31   #Mass of an electron in kg
u=1.66053907e-27    #Atomic mass unit in kg
m_Sun=1.9885e30
r_Earth=6.3781e6
n=2     #Number of baryons per electron
C=100 #Number of layers

def volume(r, R):
    return 4*np.pi/3*(R**3-r**3)

def selfBelow(m,r,x):   #The gravitational self-force of a layer below the border
    if x>r:
        return 3*G*m**2*x*(5*r**3 + 6*r**2*x + 3*r*x**2 + x*3) / (5*(r**2 + r*x + x**2)**3)
    else:
        return 1/0

def selfAbove(m,x,R):   #The gravitational self-force of a layer abpve the border
    return 9*G*m**2*x**2*(R**2 + 3*R*x + x**2)/(10*(R**2+R*x+x**2)**3)

def elseBelow(M,m,r,x):                             #The gravitational force energy from the cumulative masses on the layer below
    if x>r:
        return 3*G*M*m*x*(2*r+x)/(2*(r**2+r*x+x**2)**2)
    else:
        return 1/0

def elseAbove(M,m,x,R):                             #The gravitational force from the cumulative masses on the layer below
    if x>r:
        return 3*G*M*m*x*(2*R+x)/(2*(R**2+R*x+x**2)**2)
    else:
        return 1/0

def fermiBelow(n,r,x):    #The fermi pressure from the layer below
    if x>r:
        return -(9*pow(3/2,1/3)*pow(np.pi,2/3)*h**2*x**2)/(10*m_e)*pow(n/(x**3-r**3),5/3)
    else:
        return 1/0

def fermiAbove(n,x,R):
    if R>x:
        return -(9*pow(3/2,1/3)*pow(np.pi,2/3)*h**2*x**2)/(10*m_e)*pow(n/(x**3-r**3),5/3)
    else:
        return 1/0



V = np.frompyfunc(volume,2,1)
FSB = np.frompyfunc(selfBelow,2,1)
FSA = np.frompyfunc(selfAbove,2,1)
FEB = np.frompyfunc(elseBelow,2,1)
FEA = np.frompyfunc(elseAbove,2,1)
FFB = np.frompyfunc(fermiBelow,2,1)
FFA = np.frompyfunc(fermiAbove,2,1)

sunMasses=1

M=m_Sun*sunMasses
Particles=M/(n*u)

startRadius = h**2/(G*M**2*m_e)*pow(Particles,5/3)*pow(9*np.pi/4,2/3)
radii = startRadius*np.arange(1,C+1)/C
masses = np.ndarray(C, np.double)
masses[0:C] = M*V(np.arange(0,C),np.arange(1,C+1))/volume(0,C)
cumuMasses  = np.ndarray(C, np.double)
cumuMasses[0:C] = M*V(0,np.arange(1,C+1))/volume(0,C) #Cumulative mass of all layers below the border
N = np.ndarray(C,np.double)
N[0:C] = Particles*V(np.arange(0,C),np.arange(1,C+1))/volume(0,C)
forces      =np.zeros(C, np.double)
print(radii.dtype, masses.dtype, cumuMasses.dtype, N.dtype, forces.dtype)

for i in range(C):
    print(i)
    forces.fill(0)
    forces[0]-=FSB(masses[0], 0, radii[0]) #Special case because radii does not include 0
    forces[1:C]-=FSB(masses[1:C], radii[0:-1], radii[1:C]) #The 0:-1 index means up to, but not including, the last element
                                                        #0 is not included for reason above    
    forces[0:-1]-=FSA(masses[1:C], radii[0:-1], radii[1:C])

    forces[1:C]-=FEB(cumuMasses[0:-1], masses[1:C], radii[0:-1], radii[1,C])
    forces[0:-1]-=FEA(cumuMasses[0:-1], masses[1:C], radii[0:-1], radii[1,C])
    
    forces[0]-=FFB(N[0], 0, radii[0]) #Special case because radii does not include 0
    forces[1:C]-=FFA(N[1:], radii[0:-1], radii[1:C])

#print(forces)
```

I suspect that the culprit may be the variables I declared at the beginning, which are all probably Python's normal objects, but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: As a side tangent, why `return 1/0` instead of raising a descriptive error?

Comment: Because I don't know how to do that. I ultimately plan on getting rid of it anyway.

Comment: You probably want something like `raise ValueError(f"x must be greater than r, but got {x=} and {r=}")`

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.

Comment: There's a few things going on here but to get you past the immediate hurdle: your `frompyfunc` calls are specifying the wrong number of parameters. e.g. `selfBelow` takes 3 inputs so it should be `np.frompyfunc(selfBelow, 3, 1)` etc.

Comment: Beyond that you'll also run into troubles with `forces[...] -= FSB(...)` etc, because the ufunc produced by `frompyfunc` returns an ndarray with dtype `object`, which can't be cast automatically to `double`. I could write up an answer with the first few steps if you wanted but I think after that it will require your expert eye to debug the functions so you're better placed to do that :-)

Comment: Yeah, more broadly, you should probably just not be using `np.fromfunc` to begin with

Comment: @motto That sounds good. Let's hope I'll be able to figure the rest out for myself.

Comment: @motto, after reading your comment I realized this error was produced by a giving a `ufunc` a bad `out` parameter (which may be positional).  Earlies SO with this error used `ufunc` like `np.add` or `np.log`.  The fact that `selfBelow` requires 3 arguments produces a different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is complaining about the "return arrays"; it doesn't say anything about the type of the "input arrays".

Working from @motto's comment, and previous SO with this error, I realized that this error has to do with the `out` parameter of a `ufunc`.

For example with a common `np.add`, if I call it with:

```
In [92]: np.add(1,2,3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[92], line 1
----> 1 np.add(1,2,3)
        np.add = <ufunc 'add'>
        np = <module 'numpy' from 'C:\\Users\\paul\\miniconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py'>

TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType
```

The `help` signature of `np.add` is

```
 add(x1, x2, /, out=None, *, ...
```

It can be called with 3 arguments (plus kwargs), but the third is the `out`, which must be `None` or an array; `3` is wrong.

Specify an `out` of the right size array, and it works:

```
In [96]: np.add(1,2,np.array(5))
Out[96]: array(3)
```

Or to define a `frompyfunc` with a wrong number of inputs as you do:

```
In [97]: def foo(a,b,c):        # 3 arguments
    ...:     print(a,b,c)
    ...:     return a+b+c
    ...:     
In [98]: f = np.frompyfunc(foo,2,1)   # mistakenly using 2

In [99]: f(1,2,3)            # and calling f with 3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[99], line 1
----> 1 f(1,2,3)
        f = <ufunc 'foo (vectorized)'>

TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType
```

Calling `f` with just 2 arguments gets around this `out` problem, but then runs into a problem with the number of arguments the `foo` requires:

```
In [103]: f(1,2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[103], line 1
----> 1 f(1,2)
        f = <ufunc 'foo (vectorized)'>

TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'
```

Specifying an array `out`, has another problem; `frompyfunc` returns an object dtype array:

```
In [104]: f(1,2,np.array(5))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[104], line 1
----> 1 f(1,2,np.array(5))
        f = <ufunc 'foo (vectorized)'>
        np = <module 'numpy' from 'C:\\Users\\paul\\miniconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py'>

UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'foo (vectorized)' output from dtype('O') to dtype('int32') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

Using an object dtype array as `out`, gets us back to the problem providing enough arguments to `foo`:

```
In [105]: f(1,2,np.array(5,object))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[105], line 1
----> 1 f(1,2,np.array(5,object))
        f = <ufunc 'foo (vectorized)'>
        np = <module 'numpy' from 'C:\\Users\\paul\\miniconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py'>

TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'
```

You are using `frompyfunc` because you need the `r>x` if test, which only works for scalars.  Often there are better ways of dealing with tests like this.

Using `frompyfunc`:

```
In [112]: def foo(a,b):
     ...:     if a>b:
     ...:         return a+b
     ...:     else:
     ...:         return 0    
In [113]: f = np.frompyfunc(foo,2,1)
In [115]: f(np.arange(5),2)
Out[115]: array([0, 0, 0, 5, 6], dtype=object)
```

Many `ufunc` like `np.add` handle a `where/out` pair of arguments:

```
In [116]: def foo1(a,b):
     ...:     return np.add(a,b,where=a>b, out=np.zeros_like(a))    
In [117]: foo1(np.arange(5),2)
Out[117]: array([0, 0, 0, 5, 6])
```

Or just the regular `where`:

```
In [119]: a=np.arange(5); b=2; np.where(a>b,a+b,0)
Out[119]: array([0, 0, 0, 5, 6])
```

This evaluates `a+b` in full, and then selects values; the [116] `where` is useful where the action produces an error or `runtimewarning`.  You can also use masks to set some values according to condition, etc.

In short `np.vectorze` and `np.frompyfunc` can be useful when the function must take scalars.  But even then a simple list comprehension might be just as good.

This old SO involving `np.log` could almost be used as a [duplicate]

[TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType for a function that uses only floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911046/typeerror-return-arrays-must-be-of-arraytype-for-a-function-that-uses-only-floa)

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html

Comment: I don't understand what the `In[#]` and `Out[#]` mean. I'm also not sure what you mean by `out` or `where`. I'm pretty new to NumPy and I haven't found any tutorials that cover more than the absolute basics.

Comment: Don't depend just on tutorials; you should become familiar with official `numpy` documentation. `np.frompyfunc` isn't, what I'd call, numpy basics.  But from it's docs, its signature is `frompyfunc(func, /, nin, nout, *[, identity])`, where `nin` and `nout` are the number of input arguments of `func` and the number of returns.  `np.vectorize` is, I think, designed to be a bit more novice friendly, but even with that I see SO where novice don't read its docs carefully enough.

Comment: While I'm something of a `numpy` expert, I hadn't seen this error before.  That may be because I'm used to using `frompyfunc` (and other `ufunc`) correctly,  It took a while to realize the nature of this error message.

Comment: I fixed the number of arguments in all of my `frompyfunc`'s, and now I get this error: `numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncOutputCastingError: Cannot cast ufunc 'subtract' output from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') with casting rule 'same_kind'`. This seems like the kind of error you were talking about before with frompyfunc returning an array of objects. What would you recommend I do? Also, I read the docs, and they weren't helpful.

Comment: try adding your own `astype(float)`

Comment: I tried adding it in two different places. They got these errors:

`V = np.frompyfunc(volume,2,1).astype("float64") AttributeError: 'numpy.ufunc' object has no attribute 'astype'`

`forces[0]-=FSB(masses[0], 0, radii[0]).astype("float64")
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'astype'`

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it by putting `np.array()` around the `FSB()` function.

Comment: Yes, `astype` is a method of a numpy array, such as one produced by `FSB(...)`.  `FSB` itself is just a function, and doesn't have this method.  Looks like `FSB` with scalar inputs returns a float, the same thing that `volume` produces.  That too doesn't have this method.  And it wasn't giving problems.  It's lines like `forces[1:C]-=FSB(...)` that had problems casting the `object` dtype result from `FSB` to the float dtype of `forces`.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant.